# SwiftUI EnvironmentObject passing in @StateObject vs creating instance inline causes different behaviour

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am passing EnvironmentObjects at the app level so that I can access them throughout the app. I am creating them in line like so:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MainContentView()
            .environmentObject(NavigationStackManager())
            .environmentObject(CalendarVM())
    }
}
```

I would expect to have the same behaviour when I do this implementation:

```
@StateObject private var navigationManager = NavigationStackManager()

var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainContentView()
                .environmentObject(navigationManager)
                .environmentObject(CalendarVM())
        }
    }
```

However when I do the second implementation I get some strange states, namely subviews in the NavigationStack are reseting some of the properties.

The behaviour is as expected again, when I pass all of the @StatObjects in like so

```
@StateObject private var navigationManager = NavigationStackManager()
@StateObject private var calendarVM = CalendarVM()

var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainContentView()
                .environmentObject(navigationManager)
                .environmentObject(calendarVM)
        }
    }
```

I am trying to understand 1. what is the difference between the 3 implementations:)

Comment: It is never safe to create objects on the body StateObject is safe because it gets storage within SwiftUI instead of being recreated. SwiftUI can create/recreate structures at anytime.

Comment: `@StateObject` means call `body` when any of the `@Published` properties change. Since your `body` doesn't use any of the properties it means you've got it in the wrong place in the `View` hierarchy. `body` is called needlessly in this example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, I think the two first approaches are unsafe. And you might see that, somehow, the View didn't meet the gap and didn't re-render. So it still keeps the same instances. The right way to do is:

```swift
@StateObject private var navigationManager = NavigationStackManager()
@StateObject private var calendarVM = CalendarVM()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MainContentView()
            .environmentObject(navigationManager)
            .environmentObject(calendarVM)
    }
}
```

By this way, the entire app will keep the same instances of both NavigationStackManager and CalendarVM, instead of creating them again.